# The Dysfunctional Coat Check Problem

Tags: probability

Suppose five people check their coats in a checkroom, but all the claims attached to the coats are randomly rearranged by some kids that snuck in. In an effort to fix things, an employee rearranges the tags once more. (It ends up basically being random as to where the tags ended up after both arrangements took place.) What is the probability that:

A) all the tags are correctly assigned

B) less than two tags are correctly assigned

Comment: Does it matter that the tags were rearranged twice, if the end result is a random permutation?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, the end result was a random arrangement of the tags. There are $3$ questions that you should answer in order to determine the probabilities:

> $(A)$ How many ways can the tags be arranged, altogether?
>
> $(B)$ How many correct ways are there to arrange the tags?
>
> $(C)$ How many ways can less than two tags be correctly assigned?

I leave the answering of $(A)$ and $(B)$ to you, and I'll walk you through most of $(C)$.

Note that if four tags are correctly arranged, then they are *all* correctly arranged (why?). The possible numbers of misplaced tags, then, are $0,2,3,4,5$. For $(C)$, we are interested in the total number of ways that either $4$ or $5$ tags are misplaced. It will be easier to count the other ways, and just subtract those from the total--that is, subtract those from the answer to $(A)$.

The number of ways for zero tags to be misplaced is the answer to $(B)$.

There are $\binom52$ pairs of tags that could be misplaced, and if only two tags are misplaced, then they are necessarily switched with each other, meaning there's only one arrangement for a given pair. Hence, there are $\binom52$ ways for exactly two tags to be misplaced.

There are $\binom53$ trios of tags that could be misplaced, and if only three tags are misplaced, then there are two possible ways they could be misplaced (why?). Hence, there are $\binom53\cdot 2$ ways for exactly three tags to be misplaced.

Now, to find the answer to $(C)$, simply take the answer to $(A)$, then subtract $\binom52$, $\binom53\cdot 2$, and the answer to $(B)$.